# How to add nameRelativeToCRLIssuer To CRL using OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

I'm trying to create a certificate using OpenSSL with a nameRelativeToCRLIssuer attribute for the DistributionPoint URL, rather than a fullName attribute.  I've been using the following extfile.cnf to attempt generation of a nameRelativeToCRLIssuer:

```
    crlDistributionPoints=crldp1_section

    [crldp1_section]
    namerelativetocrlissuer=URI:http://www.example.com/root.crl
```

and signed with the following openssl command:

```
    openssl x509 -req -in signingrequest.csr -extfile extfile.cnf -CAform PEM -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out certificate.pem -days 1825
```

which creates the following certificate [with a few pieces redacted, since this is a business context]:

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number: 10317047815326669373 (0x8f2d845373441a3d)
Signature Algorithm: .....
    Issuer: .....
    Validity
        Not Before: Mar 18 19:46:21 2016 GMT
        Not After : Mar 17 19:46:21 2021 GMT
    Subject: .....
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
            Public-Key: (256 bit)
            pub: 
                04:23:39:f3:76:a6:cf:35:6d:af:9b:39:7a:87:57:
                be:4b:c3:05:01:17:3e:4a:bb:de:44:ce:88:c0:91:
                2d:92:5c:c5:d7:0e:f4:a4:e6:8c:25:58:a1:bb:38:
                e9:be:22:d6:9a:04:ac:6d:f9:35:c8:ec:fe:48:0a:
                c3:0d:6f:14:1f
            ASN1 OID: prime256v1
            NIST CURVE: P-256
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 


Signature Algorithm: .....
```

According to the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.13) it's a choice variable between fullName and nameRelativeToCRLIssuer.  I've been banging my head against the wall about this for several days with no real progress made.  Any help anyone could give would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the OpenSSL [`x509v3_config` docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/x509v3_config.html), rather than using:

```
crlDistributionPoints=crldp1_section

[crldp1_section]
namerelativetocrlissuer=URI:http://www.example.com/root.crl
```

You'd want to do something like:

```
crlDistributionPoints=crldp1_section

[crldp1_section]
relativename=@relname_section

[relname_section]    
C       = US
O       = Org, Inc.
0.OU    = Org Unit 1
1.OU    = Sub Org Unit 2
CN      = relative common name
```

Interestingly, using OpenSSL, the `relativename` value is for specifying only a (relative) *DN*, not a URI such as can be done using the `fullname` value.

For an additional example, see [here](http://marc.info/?l=openssl-dev&m=108119775817699).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much this did exactly what I needed it to!  I will comment though that it threw an error when I gave it all of the different relname_section arguments, but once I lowered the arguments to just one (C=whatever) it passed!